# UISearch and TableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar, uitableview, searchbar

**When I searching and then select row that opens only the first letter (for example A.Others letters don't open. NSLog and breakpoint not helping. I don't understand what is the problem.**

```
@synthesize propertyList,  letters, filteredNames, searchController , arrayPlace;

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

       ............
    filteredNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]init];


    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"names" ofType:@"plist"];
    self.propertyList = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.letters = [[self.propertyList allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

.......
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell bg1.png"]];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;



    if (tableView.tag == 1){

        NSString *letter = self.letters[indexPath.section];;
        NSArray *keyValues = [[self.propertyList[letter] allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
        cell.textLabel.text = keyValues[indexPath.row];
    } else{
        cell.textLabel.text = filteredNames[indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *keyTitle = cell.textLabel.text;


    NSDictionary *peopleUnderLetter = [self.propertyList objectForKey:self.letters[indexPath.section]];

    __block NSDictionary *selectedPerson = nil;

    [peopleUnderLetter enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        if ([key isEqualToString:keyTitle]) {

            selectedPerson = obj;

            *stop = YES;

        }

    }];

    if (selectedPerson) {

        DetailViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
        // Push the view controller.
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

        [vc setDictionaryGeter:selectedPerson];
    }

}
```

And :

```
#pragma mark Search Display Delegate Methods

-(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString

{

    [filteredNames removeAllObjects];
    if (searchString.length > 0) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [search] %@", self.searchBar.text];

        for (NSString *letter in letters) {
            NSArray *matches = [[self.propertyList[letter] allKeys]filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

            [filteredNames addObjectsFromArray:matches];

        }

    }

    return YES;

}
```

Search bar fails and he does select row after searching
If you want more information just say it to me by answers and I will edit my question and then you will edit your answer

Comment: all the sentences have "ana" in it which search results are filtered I guess?

Answer (score 1):

Please explain again clearly. You search using any alphabet, it shows the result which has only "A". Is this what you're trying to say ? If so, then remove the above code and try the below approach :-

> 1. Drag a search bar into the view controller and set its delegate to self (You'll find its property in the storyboard's delegate property
>      to the view controller).
> 2. Add UISearchBarDelegate in the .h file that will take care of automatically calling the appropriate methods of the search bar of
>      which the delegate is set to **self**.
> 3. Use the below method to detect the search. You can filter the NSArray here and reload the table.

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

}
```

I'd recommend you to go through some basic tutorials about iOS development before getting deeper. All the best and I hope it helps you...

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nADZ.png)

Comment: It shows every letters.But when i click at except the first cell it doesn't open detailview

Comment: Please check screenshot. Added in your answer

Comment: I don't see any screenshots. Please make sure that you've added it

Comment: I added screenshot in my question too.

Comment: Okay... It works well and what is the problem you're facing ? Is it about substring ? You need "Exact term which is searching" ?

Comment: Make sure that you've implemented logic inside cell didselectrowatindexPath method. For example, performsegue.

Comment: The  problem that is it does not open cell after searching

Comment: Open cell means ? Can you elaborate that ? What it needs to do after selecting a cell ?

Comment: after selecting every cell  must open the detailviewcontroller with their data

Comment: So, create a modal segue from your view controller and use the below code :-

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"<Your segue name>" sender:nil];
}

Comment: How create this? I am new.Help me.Give me tutorial or another link

Comment: Tell me how you're defining number of rows in a table ? Are you using any delegate methods like numberofrowsinasection ?

Comment: Try following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mv30rkczGqQ and also please follow some more basic tutorials about these basic concepts in the iOS. Because, it is very important to learn these concepts before getting deeper.

Comment: I don't know what to do.Nothing helps.
I think this is the problem ~NSDictionary *peopleUnderLetter = [self.propertyList objectForKey:self.letters[indexPath.section]];~

Comment: It it is not much secured, please send me your xcode project by compressing.. to dhiranontrack@gmail.com

Comment: please check your mail

Comment: No I didn't receive any email. My email id is (dhiranontrack@gmail.com)

Comment: Got it... Conversations are becoming more... Come in hangout